# Vue data not changing with Promise inside created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, promise, vuejs3

I noticed that Vue isn't updating the table when the promise completes. If I do a single API call with `then()` (using axios) it DOES work, so I am not sure what the `Promise` is doing which is breaking it, considering that if I `console.log(this)` it still is referencing the `Proxy`...

```html
<template>
  <table class="w-full text-left">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Domain</th>
        <th>Category</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="property in properties" :key="property.id">
        <td>{{ property.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ property.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ property.domain }}</td>
        <td>{{ property.category.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import api from '@/api';

export default {
  mounted() {
    Promise
      .all([
        api.get('properties'),
        api.get('categories'),
      ])
      .then(result => {
        let properties = result[0].data;
        const categories = result[1].data;

        properties.forEach((property) => {
          property.category = categories.find(c => c.id === property.category_id)
        });

        this.properties = properties;
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is `properties` defined in your `data`?

Comment: Add `data: () => ({ properties: [] })` to your component

Comment: no, it isnt. it doesnt set it when it comes in?

Comment: hmm...... so that fixed it. can you make it as the answer and explain why i need to set defaults ?

Comment: The duplicate link covers everything in extreme detail but you can also check the official guide ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Comment: If you're using a development build then you should have been getting a console warning telling you that the property was used during render but wasn't defined anywhere.

Comment: ah... so that is what that means

Comment: Searching for the error message might have brought about quicker resolution; YMMV.